# Visual Studio Code: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system while trying to install pylint on Linux Mint

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I did a fresh install of Linux Mint 18.3. Afterwards, installed Visual Studio Code, and a Python extension, setting python3 as an interpreter. When open a file with a .py file extension, VSC suggests that pylint gets installed. After I select "install", I get the following in the integrated terminal:

```
sh-4.3$ "/usr/bin/python3" -m pip install -U pylint
Collecting pylint
  Using cached pylint-1.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting mccabe (from pylint)
  Using cached mccabe-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting isort>=4.2.5 (from pylint)
  Using cached isort-4.2.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting astroid<2.0 (from pylint)
  Using cached astroid-1.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six (from pylint)
  Using cached six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wrapt (from astroid<2.0->pylint)
  Using cached wrapt-1.10.11.tar.gz
Collecting lazy-object-proxy (from astroid<2.0->pylint)
  Using cached lazy_object_proxy-1.3.1-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: mccabe, isort, six, wrapt, lazy-object-proxy, astroid, pylint
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.5.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.5.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.5.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.5.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.5.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.5.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 346, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.5.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 324, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 115, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mccabe.py'
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I tried to change the owner of /usr/lib/python3.5/ and its subdirectories to me, but that didn't help.

How can I fix it? Many thanks.

Comment: This is a strange error, you could probably just use a virtualenv to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best options are to either create a virtual environment or to use a user install.

For the virtual environment, if you create it in the directory you have opened in VS Code then the extension will pick it up and use it by default. You can then install Pylint into the virtual environment.

Alternatively, you can install Pylint globally with `/usr/bin/python3 install --user --upgrade pylint`. That will install it into your user directory for the version of Python that `python3` is. (This will become the default functionality in the `2018.1` release.)

Comment: Hi Brett, thank you very much for the suggestions - both of the options worked in the end. I've decided to go with a virtual environment as you've suggested though and found that it takes a lot of issues like this away. Thanks again.!